# Water molecule Resonant Frequency

Tags: thermodynamics, water, frequency

If water is subjected to microwave energy at the water's exact resonant frequency but 90 degrees out of phase, would the water molecule cease vibrating? Would the water then freeze or be cooled at least?

Comment: Not sure about the question, but a MASER is a coherent source of microwaves, actually built and working **before** the laser, so a concept which can be tested experimentally. Back in 5 mins.

Comment: Various technologies of maser, and now infra red and sub millimetre types available.  Little on maser experiments apart from: **https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xmTxCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA295&lpg=PA295&dq=maser+water+vapour+absorption&source=bl&ots=AgvNiw43EX&sig=Qwbr1avUIANapdZkAuQ3zs-w994&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwy43ppsbLAhVCxxQKHXtuAJsQ6AEIMDAG#v=onepage&q=maser%20water%20vapour%20absorption&f=false**

Comment: What do you mean by 90 degrees out of phase? Out of phase compared to what?  A resonant frequency is simply a value.  You must have a specific reference oscillator in order to define a phase difference for some other oscillator.

Comment: related question here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169173/what-is-the-resonant-frequency-of-liquid-water

Answer (score 1):

Note that water molecules don't typically exist in isolation, and as they interact with other molecules their phase will change randomly.

While in principle it might be possible to extract a little bit of energy, sometimes, from an individual molecule if you hit it just right, in practice you can't do that on an ensemble of molecules.

Comment: I was going for the "in principal" I guess. I thought by slowing or stopping the vibration of the molecule by exposing it to RF vibration out of phase the water would become solid or freeze. Similar to noise canceling circuits in electronics.  More than likely a ridiculous idea anyway.

Comment: To freeze you need more than one molecule...

Comment: I was talking about all the molecules exposed to the RF of course. I will specify the number. How about 6.022 times 10 to the 23 power molecules. This is approximately the number of molecules in a liter of water.

Comment: Avogadro's number is one mole or 18 milliliter of water...

Comment: OK if you say so.